# simple Restful call results in InvocationTargetException

Tags: httpclient, seam, resteasy

I'm using Seam with RestEasy.  RestEasy provides httpClient type functionality, among other things.

An action of mine that is called when a page loads (that is, it is called from the xxx.page.xml).  The code looks like:

```
try {
  ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(url);
  ClientResponse response = null;
  response = request.get();

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the e.printStackTrace() is never reached, but while trying the request.get(), the code generates the following exception:

> Exception during request processing:
>   Caused by javax.el.ELException with message: "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:339)
org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
org.jboss.seam.core.Expressions$2.invoke(Expressions.java:175)
org.jboss.seam.navigation.Page.preRender(Page.java:311)
org.jboss.seam.navigation.Pages.preRender(Pages.java:350)
org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.preRenderPage(SeamPhaseListener.java:561)
org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:472)
org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:148)
org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:118)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:214)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:96)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)

Why would a Reflection API call even be involved????

Comment: Please, give more details of the problem. Show page.xml snippet that calls your action, show your action source code. InvocationTargetException often wraps the actual exception happened inside the method call, may be you missed the rootCause of exception?